# Run command one after the other from bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo, sh, mkdir

I'm trying to run some commands one after the other, but I think I'm making some mistake since only the first command is being run.
I have a bash script that is like:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su && mkdir ./my_folder
```

And when I run the script only the sudo command is working but no folder is created.
Sorry if it is a trivial question.

Comment: Please explain with 'normal words' what you want to do with your bash shellscript: What do you want to do with `sudo su`, why do you run it before `mkdir ./my_folder` ? Have you tried to simply put each command on a separate line (instead of on the same line with `&&` between them)? Or simply `sudo mkdir ./my_folder` (maybe that is what you want)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo su` is a comment that spawns a new shell as the root user. The `&&` means that bash waits until the previous comment finishes successfully before executing the next (the `mkdir` command).

However, due to the `sudo su` call, you are still in a root shell. When you then enter exit you would quit the root shell, and then you would drop back to your regular user shell and bash would execute the mkdir call, as your user instead of as root.

If you want to execute a single command as root, try `sudo mkdir ./my_folder`. That way you're explicitly telling sudo to run this one command as root, and not spawn a whole new shell.